# Explorer sort order by date (not by type)

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting, date

Why Explorer in Windows 7 keeps grouping files by type when I want them by date?

Each group is sorted by date (modified), but I would like all files sorted by date (mixed types, like an old'n'good DIR command).

Answer (score 1):

In Explorer windows press <kbd>alt</kbd>, it'll show you an old style panel on the top of the window. There select `View` -> `Group by` and deselect grouping criteria.